# ¿Cómo escribir sobre un dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net, web, dropdownlist

Hola estoy trabajando en un dropdownlist dentro de asp.net que carga datos desde sql y tiene el atributo autopostback=true, ya que al seleccionar una opción se cargan las opciones de otro dropdown.

Estoy buscando alternativas para poder escribir sobre el dropdown para filtrar el proveedor a seleccionar.

Intenté con [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) pero no funcionó al hacer el postback dentro del update panel. ¿Hay alguna librería o forma de llevar esto a cabo?

Answer (score 0):

Autopastback lo que hace es que cuando seleccionas un elemento de la lista refresca la página para enviar el valor seleccionado al server, yo te recomendaría que buscar la info desde la página con $.Ajax y llenes tu el dropdownlist!